# What is a word for a person who is always concerned with what might have been?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word for a person who is always concerned with possibilities? For example, they decided to not go to a party with their friends but then wonders what may have happened if they had gone? Or perhaps what would have happened had they not decided to go buy a sandwich and coincidentally meet an old friend at that shop who offered them a much-needed job?

Comment: Not a sIngle-word (hence a comment rather than an answer), but there is a phrase **living in the subjunctive (mood)**

Comment: The person is habitually haunted by *second thoughts*.

Comment: Defeatist  for first example fatalist for second

Comment: @Drew suggests something close to what i was thinking .. "second guessing yourself"  --- "secondguesser" , or "second guessing" without "yourself" means something different.

Comment: .... *Doubtful*?

Comment: the "wistful" emotion is another close possibilitly

Comment: Does anxious not fit that bill? Under the meaning of someone who is always second-guessing whether their choice was the best course of action

Answer (score 0):

**"ambivalent"** or **"feeling ambivalent"** ("uncertain of his convictions")  seems to fit.

> - [ambivalent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ambivalent) - (adj) "having or showing ambivalence: ambivalent feelings."
> - from [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambivalent) - having or showing simultaneous and contradictory attitudes or feelings toward something or someone :  characterized by ambivalence.

- "Americans are deeply ambivalent about the country's foreign role."
- " Sigmund Freud further developed this definition in his description of ambivalent feelings as the experience of love and hate toward the same object."

Depending on context, **"insecure"**, **"diffident"**, **"doubtful"** or **"unsure"** might be more appropriate than "ambivalent".

Answer (score 0):

How about **wistful**?

M-W:

[**wistful**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wistful): Full of yearning or desire tinged with melancholy

Answer (score 0):

**Ruminator** might work; according to Merriam-Webster, to [ruminate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ruminate) is "to go over in the mind repeatedly and often casually or slowly."

Answer (score -1):

**Follower** ?
 2. a person who follows another in regard to his or her ideas or belief.
3. a person who imitates, copies, or takes as a model or ideal. 
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/follower
                                      "I'm definitely a leader, not a follower."
"I have discovered it's much safer to be a follower."